# plot3 in Matlab and axes?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm encountering weird problem with plot3. I'm getting (p, theta, phi) and I converted them to the Cartesian coordinates. My calculations is based on the following picture.

[image: spherical coordinates]

```
[p theta phi] = getmeasurement(x, y, z);
x' = p*cos(theta)*sin(phi);
y' = p*sin(theta)*sin(phi);
z' = p*cos(phi);
```

Now, I have (x', y', z') but if I use

> plot3(x', y', z')

I'm getting reverse results. I have to switch z' with x' to get the correct results as following

> plot3(z', y', x')

Why this is happening?

Comment: try changing the view angles, see help view;

Comment: and avoid using x', use x2 instead. ' has a special meaning (transpose) in matlab

Comment: @Guddu, thanks for the advice. I'm aware of the transpose just I wanna be more clear. I'm printing also another data, how can I customize specific data so that all data is plotted in one graph?

Comment: if your x,y,z are vectors (sequence of data points), like for 2 points `x=[1 2]; y=[2 3]; z=[10 20];`. To plot a line in 3D joining them, do `plot3(x,y,z)`. To plot points separately, `plot3(x,y,z,'+')`, where `+` is a symbol. To plot each point one by one (like in a loop) use `hold on` like `plot3(x(1),y(1),z(1),'+'); hold on; plot3(…)` you need to use `hold on` only once in a figure.

Comment: what I'm asking is that I have three 3D data and each one has x, y, and z data as points. I don't have problem with the first two. The last one however need to be modified to match the first two data(not the data but how the data is plotted). I can do it as I mentioned in my post but it doesn't seem intuitive.

Comment: this is weird. this might be a stupid question, but are your angles in degrees or radians?

Comment: the angles are in radians

Answer (score 0):

This happenes becauese matlab is using the labels x y and z other than your example.

The axis pointing to the right is x, the axis pointing up is y.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How can I change the order of axes to match my calculations?